# Apache - allow only clients with certain SSL certificates to access (POST) certain endpoint

Tags: php, apache, authentication, ssl, soap

I have an application written in PHP that is accessible using PHP-FPM and Apache stack.

I want single endpoint of this application (say `POST /create`, which is a SOAP service) to be accessible only for requests of clients that present valid and trusted SSL certificate. By "trusted" I mean pointing to single (or many) certificates, not just a "certfificate that is valid, because it's CA is valid".

I've tried number of ways to solve it, but I purposely not present them here to not make any suggestions, which may be just wrong by design.

Internet is returning me a rubbish full of tutorials of how to generate SSL certificates or how to make client use SSL certificates for authentication which are not the case this time.

Is there any good human being that will help me?

Comment: not certain from text, but i think you mean 'client SSL auth with apache'. If so, you could reading **[this](https://stuff-things.net/2015/09/28/configuring-apache-for-ssl-client-certificate-authentication/)** to begin your quest.

Comment: It looks promising, thank you. And yes, I mean "client SSL authentication using Apache".

Answer (score 3):

I came to some point, that I can call solution so I post it here.

There were following factors of success involved:

1. Crucial: making sure that `SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs` is enabled for certain virtual host (or globally) - it was surprisingly commented (Debian Jessie).
2. The certificate used for client authentication was signed by official (well known and public) CA, so there was no need to add self-signed CA to the server's OpenSSL environment. In other case the mentioned [very well written tutorial](https://stuff-things.net/2015/09/17/client-certificate-ca-setup-and-signing/) would help with installing custom CA and generating related client certificates.
   Thank you @YvesLeBorg.
3. For the final authentication conditions I used `.htaccess`:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
       <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/create' && %{REQUEST_METHOD} == 'POST'">
           SSLVerifyClient require
           Require expr %{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL} eq '1234567890ABCDEF123456789ABCDEF1'
           SSLVerifyDepth 2
       </If>
   </IfModule>
   ```

   As you can see, the verification for certain certificate is made
   using it's serial number (I'm still not sure if this is the best
   method to verify unique certificate).

These steps made `curl` requests work, but **in some environments** [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) still **can not authorize** and I don't know why...

But at this point I assume that problem is solved in the major part.